# Clique detection with JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, jsnetworkx

I'm trying to do some graph analysis with [JSNetworkX](http://jsnetworkx.org/).
Finding the centrality values works.
According to the [documentation](http://jsnetworkx.org/documentation.html#async), there is also a function called `jsnx.findCliques()`. In my case it returns an empty object.

```
var G = new jsnx.Graph();

G.addEdge("A", "B");
G.addEdge("A", "C");
G.addEdge("A", "D");
G.addEdge("C", "D");
G.addEdge("B", "E");

var central = jsnx.betweennessCentrality(G);
console.log(central) // object with useful values

var cliques = jsnx.findCliques(G);
console.log(cliques) // empty object
```

Here is the fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/mrpf5ybq/

I'm not tied to JSNetworkX. I just need a JS library for simple graph algorithms, such as centrality, cliques detection, etc.

Comment: have u tried the async method?

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/2336725.  It's a duplicate of your problem, but possibly not of the way you formulated your question.